# Using a B-1 Visa for training in a different state than on application

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, honduran-citizens

I'm currently in Honduras and applied for a visa to go for training in Miami, FL. I was given a B-1 visa with only 1 entry and in my passport it has the company name and address of where my training will be. **Is Miami, FL the only place I am able to go to with my visa?**

I got a call from the company I work with and they have other branches in Los Angeles, CA and they told me I would need to go for training there. Am I able to use the same visa I have, or will I have to go to the embassy to get a new visa to be able to go to California?

I have until Dec. 4th to travel.

Comment: Are you asking "Can I fly into Miami and drive to California?" or "Can I fly into Los Angeles?" on my existing visa?

Comment: @CGCampbell Can I fly into Miami and with another ticket can I fly to Los Angeles with my existing visa?

Answer (score 2):

If it was annotated in the visa page then I am afraid you will be questioned upon arrival, the annotations in the visa are actually there for that purpose.

Anyway, you still can try a few things:

- Get a letter from the training center stating that the training which was suppose to be held on Miami was moved to a new location, present this paper to the officer upon arrival and things should go fine;
- You can try to land at Miami as annotated, then find a way to go to the new training place.
- Talk to the embassy and figure it out officially.